# java.io.FileNotFoundException: what's the meaning of information in console?

Tags: java, file-io

I try to run a I/O java code but console this kind of information. Does this just mean the necessary input file PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv can not found? How can I check if this some other error?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/shenjiajie/Desktop/15min／PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at interfaces.Phase2IO.loadCLDemand(Phase2IO.java:249)
    at interfaces.Phase2IO.runPhaseII(Phase2IO.java:91)
    at interfaces.MainInterface.jButton2ActionPerformed(MainInterface.java:400)
    at interfaces.MainInterface.access$5(MainInterface.java:394)
    at interfaces.MainInterface$3.actionPerformed(MainInterface.java:257)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Show us your actual Java code please.

Comment: `File#exists` is a good place to start

Comment: 1) In this path: , /Users/shenjiajie/Desktop/15min／PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv , can you notice that after 15min, the forward slash looks little different, like some space is present. 2) And are you sure that you are passing with double forward slashes // between the directories like: //Users//shenjiajie//Desktop//15min//PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv ? 3) Did you mean to retrieve it from C: drive? Then pass it like: "C://Users//shenjiajie//Desktop//15min//PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression mean your file(PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv) file dose not exit in computer. The other meaning is you are wrong directory. Please check your directory.

You wrong the last "/" in the directory. Please replace with the following.

```
/Users/shenjiajie/Desktop/15min/PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove the blanks in the string "/Users/shenjiajie/Desktop/15min／PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv" (the one between "15min" and the slash, as well as the one right after that slash), and see if it works. Thanks and good luck!

EDIT: Thanks to @T.J.Crowder, actually there are not blanks - the last slash is wrong (looks like a full Chinese character). @T8Z is correct.

Comment: Interesting, there *aren't* any blanks in the filename. The `/` near the end isn't a normal `/`.

Comment: Oh yes you are right! Thanks for correcting! So actually @T8Z is correct!

Comment: Thanks a lot @T8Z :-)

Comment: >>Tsung-Ting Kuo  Welcome bro

Answer (score 0):

1. In this path:  `/Users/shenjiajie/Desktop/15min／PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv` , can you notice that after 15min, the forward slash looks little different, like some space is present.
2. And are you sure that you are passing with double forward slashes // between the directories like: `//Users//shenjiajie//Desktop//15min//PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv` ?
3. Are you using Windows, did you mean to retrieve it from C: drive? Then pass it like: `"C://Users//shenjiajie//Desktop//15min//PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv"`
4. You could use file.exists() to know if file really exists.

   ```
   File f = new File("C://Users//shenjiajie//Desktop//15min//PhaseII_Input_Demand.csv");
   if(f.exists())
   {
   //start next operation
   }
   ```